# count * twice with the same column under different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to count(*) twice the same column under different where conditions of the same column

Here is what I have; I tried many things but could not get it to work. I don't want to write two different queries.

```
SELECT somedate as date, 
count(*) as goodone, 
sum(money) as goodcost 
FROM goods 
where goodstatus=2 group by date;
```

when goodstatus = 1 that is the badone, so I also want to include that, and not write a separate query for it.

At the end, what I want is

```
somedate | goodone | badones| goodcost
```

I get a subquery returned more than one row error if I try doing a

```
(SELECT count(*) FROM goods where goodstatus=1) as badones
```

in that query above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the records based on condition instead of adding a new query

Try this way

```
SELECT somedate            AS date,
       Sum(goodstatus = 2) AS goodone,
       Sum(goodstatus = 1) AS badones,
       Sum(money)          AS goodcost
FROM   goods
WHERE  goodstatus IN ( 1, 2 )
GROUP  BY date;
```

Another way using `CASE` statement

```
count(case when goodstatus = 2 then 1 end) AS goodone,
count(case when goodstatus = 1 then 1 end) AS badones,
```

In the above `CASE` statement, `1` will be resulted when the condition is satisfied else `NULL` is resulted. `Count` aggregate will not count `NULL` values through this we can find the number of occurrence of `goodstatus = 2` or `goodstatus = 1`

Comment: wouldn't goodstatus=2 be a bool, and sum takes an int64 or unsigned int?

Comment: Jep - and thats why its working ;) - the group des the trick... Hint: Maybe you have to group by the date without the timepart - dont know your data...

Comment: Boolean type in `MySQL` is represented as `INT` when the condition is satisfied then it returns `1` else `0`

Comment: Not quite working for me, date is merely something like 2016-10-20

Comment: the issue is that goodstatus = 2 is returning a boolean and it is not mySQL.

Comment: @someman - then why have you tagged `Mysql` ? Use my second approach it will work

Comment: with the count(case when goodstatus = 2).... 

It ended up working, but I don't quite get the theory of it, how does then 1 help count all of them?

Comment: I am actually still not getting the right answer. There are some goodones and badones missing. Is there something wrong with the query?

Comment: @someman - That is not possible. Can you add sample data and expected result to prove query is not working

Comment: @someman - You can add `count(goodstatus)` to the query and see it will be the sum of `goodone` and `badones`